# Center a bezierCurve html5 canvas drawing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I have made basic drawings with html5 canvas and the basic shapes you can create have parameters to position the whole shape, below I center a circle `centerX` and `centerY` by taking the window size and dividing by 2.

```
context.beginPath();
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, Math.PI*2, false);
context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

The above drawing is nice and centered but now that I am playing with the bezier curve I can't find anything on the web that suggests how to center it.

```
// some arbitrary example
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(170, 80);
context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
context.fill();
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
context.closePath();
```

I wrote up a fiddle so there is something to work with [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8jsw9/2/). Below is the code pasted directly from my fiddle.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = $(window).width();
canvas.height = $(window).height();

var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;

function draw() {

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = '#333';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.closePath();

    // custom shape (weird shape lol)
    context.beginPath();
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    context.moveTo(170, 80);
    context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
    context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
    context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();

    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

}

draw();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's one method to accurately center your group of cubic Bezier curves**

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/6GZmp/

[image]

Step#1. **Use De Casteljau's algorithm** to plot points along each curve in your group of curves.

```
// De Casteljau's algorithm which calculates points along a cubic Bezier curve

// plot a point at interval T along a bezier curve
// T==0.00 at beginning of curve. T==1.00 at ending of curve
// Calculating 100 T's between 0-1 will usually define the curve sufficiently

function getCubicBezierXYatT(startPt,controlPt1,controlPt2,endPt,T){
    var x=CubicN(T,startPt.x,controlPt1.x,controlPt2.x,endPt.x);
    var y=CubicN(T,startPt.y,controlPt1.y,controlPt2.y,endPt.y);
    return({x:x,y:y});
}

// cubic helper formula at T distance

function CubicN(T, a,b,c,d) {
    var t2 = T * T;
    var t3 = t2 * T;
    return a + (-a * 3 + T * (3 * a - a * T)) * T
    + (3 * b + T * (-6 * b + b * 3 * T)) * T
    + (c * 3 - c * 3 * T) * t2
    + d * t3;
}
```

Step#2. **Determine the bounding box** of the curve-group by getting the minX,maxX,minY,maxY of the points you plotted in #1.  And use `max-min` to determine the width and height of the curves group.

```
var curvesWidth = maxX - minX;

var curvesHeight = maxY - minY;
```

Step#3. **Calculate the offset** needed in order to center your curves-group.

```
var offsetX=(canvas.width/2-curvesWidth/2)-curvesLeft;

var offsetY=(canvas.height/2-curvesHeight/2)-curvesTop;
```

Step#4. Knowing the offsets, you can use `context.translate` to **draw your centered curves**.

```
context.save();

context.translate(offsetX,offsetY);

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(170, 80);
context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
context.fill();

context.restore();
```

Comment: Wow I'm impressed I haven't fully immersed myself in the code above but it looks great, and I look forward to learning. I was busy earlier, otherwise I would have responded sooner, I appreciate you taking the time to organize that answer above, it was worth it, I am sure I am going to learn something cool! This should help others in the future also! :)

Comment: Great answer indeed, it's also very performant. Have my upvote, kind sir

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's a quick way of doing it. My attempt works like this:
you check each point on the x axis and compare it to the other points, if it is the most left or the most right store their position in a variable, otherwise do nothing. Once you have those points you know the width of the whole path and you can calculate an offset value to place it inside the center (because you know the canvas width). Then just add that offset value to the points coordinates and you're good:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/8jsw9/4/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("c"); var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = $(window).width(); canvas.height = $(window).height();

var centerX = canvas.width / 2; var centerY = canvas.height / 2;

var bezierSteps = [
    [130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150],
    [250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150],
    [420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100]
];
var mostLeft = 2000; var mostRight = 0;

findCenter();

function findCenter() {
    for (var i = 0; i < bezierSteps.length; i++) {
        for (var p = 0; p < bezierSteps.length; p+=2) {
            mostLeft = bezierSteps[i][p] < mostLeft ? bezierSteps[i][p] : mostLeft;
            mostRight = bezierSteps[i][p] > mostRight ? bezierSteps[i][p] : mostRight;
        }
    }
    console.log(mostLeft, mostRight) } var offset = (canvas.width - mostLeft - mostRight) / 2;

console.log(offset)

function draw() {

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = '#333';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.closePath();

    // custom shape (weird shape lol)
    context.beginPath();
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
    context.moveTo(170 + offset, 80);

    for (var i = 0, l = bezierSteps.length ; i < l ; i++) {
        context.bezierCurveTo(bezierSteps[i][0]  + offset,bezierSteps[i][1],bezierSteps[i][2] + offset,bezierSteps[i][3],bezierSteps[i][4] + offset,bezierSteps[i][5])
    }
    //context.bezierCurveTo(130, 100, 130, 150, 230, 150);
    //context.bezierCurveTo(250, 180, 320, 180, 340, 150);
    //context.bezierCurveTo(420, 150, 420, 120, 390, 100);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();

    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';

}

draw();
```

sorry for the dirty code..

Comment: Thanks for the write up, had to give you +1 for the effort... I am trying to center the x and y axis so it's dead center, the fiddle was just the x axis being centered?

Comment: Yes, but you can use the same approach for the y axis

Comment: oh okay, I didnt really look into the whole thing, thanks Ill do that now.

Comment: How do I offset the top, I am still trying to figure out how `mostLeft` and `mostRight` works lol. Would those calculations work `var offsetTop = (canvas.height - mostLeft - mostRight) / 2;`?

Comment: No, sorry but I'm no longer at my desk. I'll update the code tomorrow